# Как найти значение по колонке xml

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица T1 и в таблице есть `xml` данные колонка xmlInvoice

Вид xml данных :

```
<document>
  <payer id="105115025"/>
  <addInfo>
    <calcParams>
      <calcParam id="1" name=""/>
    </calcParams>
  </addInfo>
  <invoices>
    <invoice id="10511502520170301214621" amount="164200">
      <parameters>
        <parameter serviceId="65" serviceIdExt="65" serviceName="вода и канализация" />
        <parameter serviceId="258" serviceIdExt="258" serviceName="цифровое ТВ - ТОО"/>
      </parameters>
    </invoice>
  </invoices>
</document>
```

Нужно найти xml данные в которых содержится `serviceName="цифровое ТВ - ТОО`
Мой запрос:

```
  SELECT top 10 * 
  FROM t1 
  where 
   xmlInvoice.value('(/document/invoices/invoice/parameters/parameter)[1]','varchar(max)') like '%цифровое ТВ - ТОО%'
```

Запрос долго грузиться, что не так с запросом?

Comment: Вам лучше в xnode выборку написать `/parameter[serviceName="вода и канализация"]`

Comment: Попробуйте так  `where cast( xmlInvoice as varchar(8000)) like '%"вода и канализация"%'`

Comment: Можно и вот так SELECT TOP 10 * FROM T1 WHERE CAST(xmlInvoice AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%serviceName="цифровое ТВ - ТОО%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С таким

```
(/document/invoices/invoice/parameters/parameter)[1]
```

XPath выбирается, во-первых, первый параметр, т.е.

```xml
<parameter serviceId="65" serviceIdExt="65" serviceName="вода и канализация" />
```

во-вторых, выбирается содержимое элемента, а не атрибута serviceName.

Попробуйте так:

```sql
declare @search nvarchar(100) = N'цифровое ТВ - ТОО';

select top (10) *
from T1
where xmlInvioce.exist(
    '/document[1]/invoices[1]/invoice/parameters[1]/parameter[contains(@serviceName, sql:variable("@search"))]'
    ) = 1;
```

или так:

```sql
select top (10) *
from T1
where exists (
    select 1
    from T1.xmlInvioce.nodes('/document[1]/invoices[1]/invoice/parameters[1]/parameter') x(c)
    where x.c.value('@serviceName', 'nvarchar(100)') like '%' + @search + '%'
    );
```